# How accurate the recent activities location provided by Microsoft emails

Tags: email, privacy, attacks

One of my emails is on hotmail.com provided by Microsoft. Recently, after few suspicious incidents where my computer was hacked and many other accounts, I changed all my passwords including this email. I started ever since reviewing `recent activities` feature on daily basis. I could see many failed attempts to login to my email from different countries. It is increasing day after another. This illustrates recent few days only:

[image]

I reside in Malaysia, and I can see my successful logins in Malaysia. However, there many attempts from different countries. This gives the feeling my email is really targeted, I do not know what to do about it. Today failed, but maybe tomorrow won't. Other than changing my password and enabling 2 steps verification, I do not know what else can I do. 
Now my question is, how much these locations accurate? 
Or the hackers can virtually try from different countries although they are in one place?

What other measures I can take to stop this, or make them realize it is useless to try? 
It feels like someone is trying to break into your house consistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a strong password and 2FA should be sufficient to prevent those who knew your password from succeeding again.

Yes, it is very possible that an attacker would have access to servers around the world to try and log into your account, so that's not surprising at all. It is also possible that your account credentials were sold, posted on a public forum. There are [sites](http://www.forbes.com/sites/adamtanner/2014/04/14/these-sites-tell-which-of-your-accounts-have-been-hacked/) that try to determine if accounts are made public.

I know that its unnerving to have someone constantly try to break in, but we are all exposed to the same thing all the time. Good account practices protect us all from these types of threats.